# GitHub Pages (jekyll blog) showed 404

Tags: github, jekyll

I tried to build up a Jekyll blog website using GitHub pages. I could check the homepage, but the subpages (about & blogposts) showed 404.

To find out where the problem is, I opened a new repo. And I set up the basic things of a Jekyll site using `jekyll new .` locally and uploaded them to the Github repo. I did not change anything after this step.

And then, I used `jekyll serve` to run the local test, and everything went well. The layout looked nice and I could check the first blog "Welcome to Jekyll!"(built by default).

However, when I used the link of GitHub Pages to check, the layout of the homepage looked quite different, and I could not check the default blogpost "Welcome to Jekyll!", which showed me 404.

How can I fix it?

This is my repo: https://github.com/jl-xie-kcl/blog20211122

(you can check the screenshots in issue 2 https://github.com/jl-xie-kcl/blog20211122/issues/2)

Comment: Your GitHub Pages has already deployed at https://jl-xie-kcl.github.io/blog20211122/, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but only the homepage works. The about page and the blogpost showed 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those pages do work, your links are just incorrect because your blog is not at the root of your domain — and this goes the same for the style and images not working, by the way:

- The link to your about page: https://jl-xie-kcl.github.io/blog20211122/about
- The link to your blog post: https://jl-xie-kcl.github.io/blog20211122/jekyll/update/2021/11/22/welcome-to-jekyll.html

---

In order to fix this, you will have to change the `baseurl` value in your _*config.yml* to:

```yaml
baseurl: "/blog20211122"
```

As stated by [the comment on this configuration line](https://github.com/jl-xie-kcl/blog20211122/blob/c74dc51ef8c7458d07812c1698c16acd643257df/_config.yml#L27):

```yaml
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
```